# Using PHP preg_match to change the max-width and max-height of string

Tags: php

I have a URL string like the one below:

```
http://localhost/showimage.php?image=sunshine.jpg&max_width=158&max_height=158
```

And what I'm trying to do, with `preg_match`, is replace the `max_width` and `max_height` values to the one below:

```
http://localhost/showimage.php?image=sunshine.jpg&max_width=1000&max_height=1000
```

How can I do this using `preg_match`?

Comment: You should use `preg_replace` instead for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://localhost/showimage.php?image=sunshine.jpg&max_width=158&max_height=158';
    $changedUrl = preg_replace('/(max_width)=\d+|(max_height)=\d+/', '$1$2=1000', $url, 2);
    var_dump($changedUrl);
```

This pattern changes max_width and max_height values to 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
preg_replace(
    '/(max_width|max_height)\=\d+/i',
    '\1=1000',
    $string
)
```